# Finding The impulse acting on the bouncing ball, is it enough to mg.time or also calculate the reaction force of the ground?

Tags: kinematics, momentum

exemp: Ball with a mass of 3 kg falls for 3 seconds and rises for 2 seconds. the answer says it is 150 n.s (30N.5s) but the reaction force of the floor can change the result, right?

Comment: The question is ill-defined.   What are the starting and ending conditions:  At rest at the beginning and at the end?  It makes a difference.   Which force is the subject:  gravity, the normal force, or both.   In any event I'm having a hard time figuring out a set of conditions that leads to an impulse of 150 Ns.

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely.  150 Ns is just the impulse of gravity. 
The reaction force of the ground too provides  impulse when the ball is in contact with the ground  ( albeit for a short time interval)

Depending on the coefficient of restitution of the collision with the ground  , the magnitude of the impulse provided by reaction force can be different. ( it will be maximum for a perfectly elastic collision )

The net change of momentum of the body would be the vector sum of the impulse provided by gravity and normal reaction

Comment: Garyp , the impulse of gravity on the body during the time interval of 5s  is  150Ns  irrespective of the initial conditions and the other forces.

Comment: The statement Impulse acting on the body implies the net impulse, I.e impulse  due to all the forces

Comment: Thanks. I clearly understood.